# how to use the tortoise svn import

Tags: tortoisesvn, svn-checkout

Let's say I have checkedout a project via SVN, then I right clicked the folder and export it, what happens is, it threw a copy of the project to another folder and removed the .svn suffixes and removed the green "check" icon.

Now, if am using an IDE to develop, such as Eclipse, I create a new project and use the source files of the exported folder. If I will right click this exported folder and click the SVN import, will it transfer the edited files to the checked out folder? Is that how it works? Or am thinking the wrong thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly.. `svn import` imports files into the SVN repository, not working copy. You could however use Eclipse's import feature to import them into your Eclipse project. But really your Eclipse project should be a Working copy if you are using SVN. You can actually use Subclispe for this and mess wiht SVN directly in Eclipse instead of doing things through Tortoise. Of course if you dont have Eclipse open then Tortoise is a good general purpose tool.

Im Mac based but i use 5 different SVN clients depending on the context... Subclipse in Eclipse, SCPlugin (like Tortoise but for OS X's file manager), SVN/Project+ Bundle for Textmate, Timeline in Adobe CS, and the command line.